# How to assign multiple log for EventLog

Tags: c#-4.0, event-log

I am using EventLog class to get event log from system using below code

```
       EventLog myLog = new EventLog();           

            myLog.Log = "System";
            //myLog.Log = "Application";            
            myLog.MachineName = ".";

            int LogCount = myLog.Entries.Count;
```

However by using above code i am getting data for only 1 log at a time for "Application" OR "Security". How can i get log data for both log name ?

Comment: You mean presumably one log at a time, rather than one source (Source is a well defined term in terms of the Event log and the event logging classes, and isn't what you're working with here).